# selectinput in Shiny R

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny

I can not get the value of select input, I need to generate a cloud of words, but the content of the cloud will depend on the selected option.

The application is loading infinitely. Help me please.

UI.R

```
fluidPage(
# Application title
titlePanel("Word Cloud"),

sidebarLayout(
# Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("selection", "Choose a book:",
              choices = c(coletor1,coletor2),
        selected = coletor1),
  actionButton("update", "Change"),
  hr(),
  sliderInput("freq",
              "Minimum Frequency:",
              min = 1,  max = 1000, value = 1),
  sliderInput("max",
              "Maximum Number of Words:",
              min = 1,  max = 100,  value = 100)
),

# Show Word Cloud
mainPanel(
 tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
     tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot"))

)
```

)
   )
   )

Server.R

```
function(input, output, session) {

# Define a reactive expression for the document term matrix
terms <- reactive({
# Change when the "update" button is pressed...
input$update
# ...but not for anything else
isolate({
  withProgress({
    setProgress(message = "Processing corpus...")
    getTermMatrix(input$selection)
  })
})
})

# Make the wordcloud drawing predictable during a session
wordcloud_rep <- repeatable(wordcloud)

output$plot <- renderPlot({
v <- terms()
wordcloud_rep(names(v), v, scale=c(4,0.5),
              min.freq = input$freq, max.words=input$max,
              colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
})
}
```

Global.R

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(memoise)

library(RPostgreSQL)
con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), user="postgres",      password="123456",dbname="postgres")
coletor1=dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT REPLACE(aux_coletprinc,' ','')          aux_coletprinc  from jabot.detacesso2 where aux_coletprinc ilike '%forz%a%'
")
coletor2=dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT REPLACE(aux_coletprinc,' ','')   aux_coletprinc  from jabot.detacesso2 where aux_coletprinc ilike '%vian%a%'
")

dbDisconnect(con)
list<-c(coletor1,coletor2) 

# Using "memoise" to automatically cache the results
getTermMatrix <- memoise(function(list) {

text <- list

myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(text))
myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))

myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus,
          control = list(minWordLength = 1))

m = as.matrix(myDTM)

sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)
})
```

Comment: `global.R` runs before `server.R` and `ui.R`. Because of this, there is no `input$selection` yet. Also, variables (such as "a") must be decrared with the `<<-` operator in `global.R`.

Answer (score 2):

`global.R` runs before `server.R` and `ui.R`. Because of this, there is no `input$selection` yet.

You just have to *define* the `getTermMatrix` function in `global.R`. There is no need to define `a` nor the `text` that is going to be read.

You can do both in `server.R`, where the `input` list already exists. Altough, take a better look into your `getTermMatrix()` function, the `book` argument is never used.

Comment: I tried to do what you said but I could not, I'm still starting to use the shiny R. I just wanted the generated cloud to be able to be changed with the user's choice. Do you have any idea how I can do it?

Comment: Would please report us the new error message? Perhaps editing your question

Comment: I changed the application a bit, I do not understand why it does not work the way I want. He should carry the cloud of words according to the choice made.

Comment: Collector1 and Collector2 are variables that are some names. In my work I need the application to select these variables to generate the word cloud with the data of the selected variables. I've tried everything, but I can not make a way for selectinput to change which variable will generate the cloud of words. If I change manually in the code "text = Collector1" or "text = Collector2" I can do what I want, but I would like to make this change using the shiny system, maybe I should change it in ui.r. I do not know what to do.

Comment: I'll post too in stack overflow portuguese, but thanks fot try help me.
Obrigado.